# How to create a Hive table using Ozone?

Tags: hive, ozone

How we can create a **hive** table using **ozone object store**.

Comment: pls share what you did or where you are stuck ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a **hive** table, first we need to create a **volume** and **bucket** in **ozone**.

**Step1:** Create the volume with the name vol1 in Apache Ozone.

```
# ozone sh volume create /vol1
```

**Step2:** Create the bucket with the name bucket1 under vol1.

```
# ozone sh bucket create /vol1/bucket1
```

**Step3:** Login to beeline shell

**Step4:** Create the hive database.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ozone_db;
USE  ozone_db;
```

**Step5:** Create the hive table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee`(                  
   `id` bigint,                                     
   `name` string,                                   
   `age` smallint)
STORED AS parquet 
LOCATION 'o3fs://bucket1.vol1.om.host.example.com/employee';
```

**Note:** Update the **om.host.example.com** value.

**Reference:**

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-Hive-Ozone-Integration-in-CDP/ta-p/323346